# Access model from scope path in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive where I need to access scope at the location which is passed through attributes.

HTML:

```
<div my-directive scope-location="settings.main.url">
    ...
</div>
```

Directive:

```
link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        // How can I do
        // scope['settings']['main']['url'] = angular.element(elm).text();
        // where "['settings']['main']['url']" comes part from attr "scope-location"
        // with value "settings.main.url"?

        scope[attrs.scopeLocation] = angular.element(elm).text();
    }
```

Fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/GEhSG/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/GEhSG/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways to achieve this

- Since your directive inherits its scope from parent, the variable is available using

  `scope.settings.main.url`
- If don't want to hardcode, you can use `$parse` services like

  var location=$parse(attrs.scopeLocation);

  location(scope);
- You can create isolated scope and pass in the variable to the scope object in the directive definition, like

  scope: {
     scopeLocation:'='
  }

I have created a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/beyND/, for first two approaches.